# Including CSS and JS files in Wicket apps

Tags: wicket

I'm a first timer with the Wicket framework and trying it out for an internal project in my company. We have our own CSS files for themes and a JavaScript library built on Dojo for constructing widgets.

I have two questions about including these external resources:

1. Where should these resource folders be located? Do they go directly under the application, or should they be placed in the Java package folder along with the HTML files?
2. Will the standard way of linking CSS and JS in the `<head>` section work?

My project uses Wicket 1.5.

Comment: Thanks. I placed the resources under the application folder and referenced them with wicket:head in the html, but the themes are not applied to the page elements. Is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: I strongly recommend you use Firefox and install the Firebug plugin. This will allow you to inspect the rendered HTML, and look at the style attributes associated with each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jbrookover hinted, there used to be two ways to include CSS and JS. One is to use `<wicket:head>` tags, like this:

```
<wicket:head>
    <wicket:link>
        <link href="yourStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </wicket:link>
</wicket:head>
```

The second method was to include header contributors, like this:

```
// From v1.3; deprecated in v1.4 and removed in v1.5
add(HeaderContributor.forJavaScript(Foo.class, "yourScripts.js"));
```

or

```
// From v1.4; removed in v1.5
JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(Foo.class, "yourScripts.js")
```

There was actually a third, more complicated way, too, which involved writing a custom header contributor and `renderHead()` method. Since you're using version 1.5, the second method is unavailable, and you'll have to choose from the `<wicket:head>` tags or a slightly modified version of the complicated way. See the Wicket wiki's "Migrating to Wicket 1.5" page; specifically, the three sections that start [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5#MigrationtoWicket1.5-JavascriptLibraries).

Comment: Thanks..I will go with the wicket:head approach. I do not want to mix UI elements with my java code.