# How to add internal css (<style>) to a Wicket page

Tags: java, wicket

I need to include my css file as an *internal css* using `<style>`. How can I do that with Wicket?

I know about `renderHead()` and `<wicket:link>` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776078/including-css-and-js-files-in-wicket-apps). But that creates external links. This is for sending mail, so I need it contained in the generated html.

Comment: Just type it into the HTML file or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nicktar maybe the goal is to get a css file inlined?

Comment: @XaviLópez Thanks... I think I see the problem there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I eventually implemented it. Thanks to Nicktar for pointing in the right direction.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {

    try {
        InputStream in = new CssPackageResource(BusinessMail.class, 
                "style.css", getLocale(), "?", "?")
                .getCacheableResourceStream().getInputStream();

        String data = new java.util.Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        response.renderCSS(data, "notneeded");

    } catch (ResourceStreamNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("Could not load css", e);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without trying this...

Wouldn't a Panel implementing [IHeaderContributor](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/IHeaderContributor.html) with an renderHead method similar to thisone do the trick?

```
void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    StringBuffer myCSS = new StringBuffer();
    File file = new File("global CSS");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String s = null;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        myCSS.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    reader.close();

    response.renderCSS(myCSS, "notreallyneeded");
}
```

ommiting every error handling and proper resource closing along the way...

Note that "notreallyneeded" is not really needed in an non-Ajax environment like email. According to JavaDoc this can be `null` as well.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen `renderCSS` before. Sounds promising. Now, if we could just figure out a way to get to the CSS file in a "wicket way".

Comment: Well, I suppose a [FileResourceStream](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/util/resource/FileResourceStream.html)  with a filename relative to application root will do...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand "internal", use in wicket html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<wicket:head>

    <style type="text/css">
<!--
.aCaption {
/*  display: block; */
/*  background-color: green;*/

}
-->

</style>

</wicket:head>

  // rest of classic wicket page ...   
  <body> .... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody comes across this and wonders how to do it with a recent Wicket + Java version (in my case, JDK16 and Wicket 8.x):

```
    final PackageResourceReference prr = new PackageResourceReference( ThisPage.class, "css/my.css" )
    try ( InputStream in = prr.getResource().getResourceStream().getInputStream() )
    {
        final String css = new String( in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        response.render( new CssContentHeaderItem( css, "my.css", null ) );
    }
    catch( IOException | ResourceStreamNotFoundException e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
```